# Getting variable in iframe

Tags: php, html

I'm passing a varaible to a iframe but can't seem to access this variable via the global get variable.

```
<iframe src="uploadContract.php?clientid={$clientid}" frameborder="0" height="95"></iframe>
```

in uploadContract.php I try to access the variable like `$_GET['clientid'];`

Somehow I can't seem to get the value via the Get global

What am I doing wrong?

What I noticed is that this iframe is within another frame, if I display the iframe not within a frame it actually works. How can I get this to work within a frame?

Comment: Not to sure if it could be that the iframe is called within an frame

Comment: you have a syntax errors in your code. the code you posted won't work. is it HTML or PHP at least?

Comment: @Col it would be correct if a template like Smarty is used. @Roland Perhaps you could show the actual html output instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that the problem is in the code snippet that you present here. Are you sure that `$clientid` has a valid value when you try to use it in the above snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the html that the src is really what you think it is.
Then try var_dump($_GET); from uploadContract.php